# How to align text labels to left side of a geo_segment

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I want to add labels next to the left side of the line but there is a gap between the beginning of the line and the end of the label that seems to be associated with how long the label is. The longer the label the bigger the gap and vice-versa. Is there a way to make all the labels have the same distance from the beginning of the line? Below is toy data to mimic the issue.

```
library(tidyverse)
 data.frame(start = seq(from = 50000, to = 90000, by = 10000),
                  end = seq(from = 60000, to = 104000, by = 11000),
                  type = c("Tesla","Tesla Extended Range", "EV Volvo",
                           "EV Volvo XC90 7 Passanger","EV BMW")) %>% 
mutate(type = fct_reorder(type, start, .fun='sum' )) %>% 
ggplot +
geom_segment(aes(x = start, y = type, 
               xend = end, yend = type),
           show.legend = FALSE, alpha = .8) +
geom_text(aes(x = start, y = type, label = type),
        vjust = -1 , size = 3, hjust = 1.4, nudge_x = -1, alpha = .8) +
coord_cartesian(xlim =c(40000, NA)) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Why not set `hjust =1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `hjust=1` and shift your labels using `nudge_x`:

Note: That's one of the reason why I try to avoid setting a value for `hjust` or `vjust` outside of `[0, 1]`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(
  start = seq(from = 50000, to = 90000, by = 10000),
  end = seq(from = 60000, to = 104000, by = 11000),
  type = c(
    "Tesla", "Tesla Extended Range", "EV Volvo",
    "EV Volvo XC90 7 Passanger", "EV BMW"
  )
) %>%
  mutate(type = fct_reorder(type, start, .fun = "sum")) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(
      x = start, y = type,
      xend = end, yend = type
    ),
    show.legend = FALSE, alpha = .8
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(x = start, y = type, label = type),
    vjust = -1, size = 3, hjust = 1, nudge_x = -1000, alpha = .8
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(40000, NA)) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to use the `ggrepel` package to automatically adjust the position of the labels.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

data.frame(start = seq(from = 50000, to = 90000, by = 10000),
           end = seq(from = 60000, to = 104000, by = 11000),
           type = c("Tesla","Tesla Extended Range", "EV Volvo",
                    "EV Volvo XC90 7 Passanger","EV BMW")) %>% 
  mutate(type = fct_reorder(type, start, .fun='sum' )) %>% 
  ggplot +
  geom_segment(aes(x = start, y = type, 
                   xend = end, yend = type),
               show.legend = FALSE, alpha = .8) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(x = start, y = type, label = type),
                  size = 3, nudge_x = -5000, alpha = .8) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim =c(40000, NA)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

[image]